# sql query to fill dataset with multiple datatables based on specific column

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset

I have a SQL Server table called `tSongList` that contains the following information:

```
colAlbumID, colSongName, colAlbumTrackNumber, colRequestedCount, colPlayPriority
```

The purpose of this table is to help a DJ keep a list of which songs the DJ should play and which album they are from. I have a C# class that will take a list of songs from a specific `albumID` and calculate the `colPlayPriority` based on the `colRequestedCount`. I have designed this class to take a `DataTable` containing the columns above and compute the necessary information.

So my question is if I want to use SQL to select all the rows from the `tSongList`, how do I get the SQL result into multiple `DataTables` grouped by `colAlbumID`? In other words, I want a `DataTable` for each Album that contains it's song information.

I know that I can use a `SqlDataAdapter` to fill a `DataSet` and since a `DataSet` can contain multiple `DataTables`, is there a way to construct a SQL query to return a `DataSet` containing the `DataTables` grouped by `albumID`?

Also if this can't be done, should I just select everything into one `DataTable` and use the `Select` function to get a `DataRow` array instead?

Comment: First I would normalize your data.  You need a songs table, an albums table and a playlist table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) will show you how to do this. You will make life much easier for yourself if you properly [normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data first. You can create a hierarchical DataSet with the necessary relationships in place making it trivial to get all songs for an album.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to return a single DataTable and use LINQ to create your grouping.

```
var albumGroups = from a in dtAlbums.AsEnumerable()
  group a by a.Field<int>("albumID") into g
  select new { colSongName = g.Field<string>("colSongName"), 
               colAlbumTrackNumber = g.Field<int>("colAlbumTrackNumber"),
               colRequestedCount = g.Field<int>("colRequestedCount"),
               colPlayPriority = g.Field<int>("colPlayPriority") };
```